# How to extract important information of an AVPacket from an encoded video using FFMPEG

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, computer-vision

I wrote a code to read a video in encoded domain and able to retrieve information such as size and duration of frames. AVPacket class consist of a variable as data. I can read it but since it is a bite array I can't use it in readable format. I want to use this data for comparison with another video file. Please help.

```
void CFfmpegmethods::VideoRead(){
av_register_all();
avformat_network_init();
ofstream outdata;
const char *url = "H:\\Sanduni_projects\\Sample_video.mp4";
AVDictionary *options = NULL;
AVFormatContext *s = avformat_alloc_context(); //NULL;

AVPacket *pkt = new AVPacket();

//open an input stream and read the header
int ret = avformat_open_input(&s, url, NULL, NULL);

//avformat_find_stream_info(s, &options); //finding the missing information 

if (ret < 0)
    abort();

av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "640x480", 0);
av_dict_set(&options, "pixel_format", "rgb24", 0);

if (avformat_open_input(&s, url, NULL, &options) < 0){
    abort();
}

av_dict_free(&options);

AVDictionaryEntry *e;

if (e = av_dict_get(options, "", NULL, AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Option %s not recognized by the demuxer.\n", e->key);
    abort();
}

int i = 1;
int j = 0;
int64_t duration = 0;
int size = 0;
uint8_t *data = 0; //Unsigned integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.
int sum = 0;

int total_size = 0;
int total_duration = 0;
int packet_size = 0;
int64_t stream_index = 0;
int64_t bit_rate = 0;

//writing data to a file
outdata.open("H:\\Sanduni_projects\\log.txt");

if (!outdata){
    cerr << "Error: file could not be opened" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

//Split what is stored in the file into frames and return one for each call
//returns the next frame of the stream

while(1){
    int frame = av_read_frame(s, pkt);
    if (frame < 0) break;

    duration = pkt->duration;
    size = pkt->size;

    total_size = total_size + size;
    total_duration = total_duration + duration;

    cout << "frame:" << i << " " << size << " " << duration << endl;
    data = pkt->data;
    outdata << "Frame: " << i << " ";
    outdata << data<< endl;

    for (j = 0; j < size; j++){

    }

    i++;
    //pkt_no++;
    //outdata << sum << endl;       
}

//make the packet free
av_packet_unref(pkt);
delete pkt;

cout << "total size: " << total_size << endl;
cout << "total duration:" << total_duration << endl;

outdata.close();

//Close the file after reading
avformat_close_input(&s);
```

}

Comment: What's your question? You're describing problems you're having, but you don't have a question in your question...

Comment: I want to print or use the information in "data" parameter and use it for comparisons and extract useful information contained.

Comment: Okay. That's what you want to do. Now formulate a question and add that to your... question.

Comment: What do you mean? I can't understand.

Comment: You're expressing what you *want to do*. A question has a question mark and is... a question. On SO everything is questions, so your question should have, you know, a question in it!

Answer (score 2):

> I can't use it in readable format

Why do you want that? You want to output details of you [AVPAcket](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/structAVPacket.html)? Then you need to get these details from your [AVFormatContext](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/structAVFormatContext.html). `AVPacket` has `stream_index` and you can use that to get details of the stream that the packet represents. The other useful info is the pts/dts and size of the packet.

```
AVPacket pkt = ...;
AVFormatContext *s = ... ;

AVStream* stream = s->streams[pkt.stream_index]; // get the stream
```

Basically each media file contains multiple streams. When you open a file `AVFormatContext` stores information about the file that you open. `AVFormatContext::streams` are the streams that are part of your media file (e.g. audio, video). This way from each `AVPacket` you can get [AVStream](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/structAVStream.html) that the packet represents. In `AVStream` you can inspect `codec`, `duration` of the stream and other useful parameters.

Comment: Actually I don't need it to be readable. I just want to extract useful information from it. Basically I want to know whether it is possible to extract DCT coefficients and motion vectors. I want to use them for comparison.

Comment: @SanduniWickramasinghe that's going to be quite not easy, as you would need to go into bitstream and associated [AVCodecContext](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/structAVCodecContext.html). Possibly you'll need to parse into bitstream yourself. Try h264bitstream for that (assuming you are dealing with H264)

Comment: I don't get it. Can you please describe more.

Comment: @SanduniWickramasinghe I don't think you can easily get DCT coefficients and motion vectors just like that. Simple as that. Try x264 of ffmpeg mailing lists perhaps you can get better suggestion there or find somebody who tried to do that.